# Show image preview in full screen but capture 4:3

Tags: ios, iphone, flutter, image-scaling, flutter-camera

Using Flutter and the [camera](https://pub.dev/packages/camera) package we want to mimic the behaviour of the iOS camera when capturing in 4:3. When looking at the screen we want to show the 4:3 area that will be captured but the image preview should cover the whole screen with the area outside 4:3 partially transparent.

How can this be implemented in Flutter? If we would simply scale (Transform.scale) the CameraPreview to fit the width of the display then the image captured not correspond to what was actually seen in the 4:3 preview area.

Been trying to figure out how Apple does this but now I'm stuck.